# How do you pass a variable to VBS script in a powershell command?

Tags: variables, powershell, vbscript

I know that you can use something like:

```
$variable = "value 1"

cscript test.vbs $variable
```

but how exactly do you capture that variable inside the vbs script?
Thanks.

Comment: You should provide examples to what you've already tried to do in your vbs script

Comment: @pabrantes - what's the use of asking a person admittedly not knowing how to do X to give examples of failed attempts to do X?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: my comment was done having in mind  the information in _Do your homework_ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask I think it's fine for people not knowing things (nobody knows everything) but I don't think the idea is for SO to be Google, hence, showing a little research / code tries wouldn't hurt. But I'm new here, so I might be wrong, do you think it was overreacting from my part?

Comment: @pabrantes - I'm all for encouraging people to 'do their homework' before they ask, but in this case (and in many others), asking for *code* makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

By accessing the WScript.Arguments collection. [HowTo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156618.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

WScript.Arguments is a good way to go. Another option is to use a [WSF file](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2002/02/01/wsf-the-final-frontier.aspx) to put a bit more structure around your script.